# How to get text from property class : internet explorer_server to richtextbox

Tags: vb.net

is it possible to get text from chat application, I use spy++ and the property class is internet explorer_server and I want to display it in richtextbox,
i made it on vbnet
I've googled but can't find anything, can anyone help?

thank you

thats code i have trying but not work.

Imports mshtml
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

```
Inherits Form
<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetClassNameA")>
Public Shared Function GetClassName(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpClassName As StringBuilder, ByVal nMaxCount As Integer) As Integer

End Function
Public Delegate Function EnumProc(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Public Shared Function EnumChildWindows(ByVal hWndParent As IntPtr, ByVal lpEnumFunc As EnumProc, ByRef lParam As IntPtr) As Integer

End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="RegisterWindowMessageA")>
Public Shared Function RegisterWindowMessage(ByVal lpString As String) As Integer

End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SendMessageTimeoutA")>
Public Shared Function SendMessageTimeout(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer, ByVal fuFlags As Integer, ByVal uTimeout As Integer, <Out> ByRef lpdwResult As Integer) As Integer

End Function
<DllImport("OLEACC.dll")>
Public Shared Function ObjectFromLresult(ByVal lResult As Integer, ByRef riid As Guid, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByRef ppvObject As IHTMLDocument2) As Integer

End Function
Public Const SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG As Integer = &H2
Public IID_IHTMLDocument As New Guid("70391899-3fc0-4b82-981a-ac81bc29b40e")
Public document As IHTMLDocument2
Private Function DocumentFromDOM() As IHTMLDocument2
    Dim processes As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("Camfrog Video Chat.exe")

    If processes.Length > 0 Then
        Dim hWnd As IntPtr = processes(0).MainWindowHandle
        Dim lngMsg As Integer = 0
        Dim lRes As Integer
        Dim proc As New EnumProc(AddressOf EnumWindows)
        EnumChildWindows(hWnd, proc, hWnd)

        If hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then

            Return document
        End If
        lngMsg = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_HTML_GETOBJECT")

        If lngMsg <> 0 Then
            SendMessageTimeout(hWnd, lngMsg, 0, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, lRes)

            If Not (lRes = 0) Then
                Dim hr As Integer = ObjectFromLresult(lRes, IID_IHTMLDocument, 0, document)

                If (document Is Nothing) Then
                    MessageBox.Show("No IHTMLDocument Found!", "Warning")
                End If
            End If
        End If

        Return document
    End If

    Return document
End Function
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    document = DocumentFromDOM()

    If Not (document Is Nothing) Then
        RichTextBox2.Text = document.url
    End If
End Sub

Private Function EnumWindows(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
    Dim retVal As Integer = 1
    Dim classname As New StringBuilder(128)
    GetClassName(hWnd, classname, classname.Capacity)

    If String.Compare(classname.ToString(), "Internet Explorer_Server") = 0 Then
        lParam = hWnd
        retVal = 0
    End If

    Return retVal
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: Please consider adding some code you have tried

Comment: @Vector I have edited in the question column by embedding the code that I have tried